# cakephp error message Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, cakephp

i have function which culullate average rate of the teacher and i save the average on the variable $result i want pass the variable to the get_teacher_average_rating and print the average , but i try do that i have error

> Too few arguments to function RatingSchoolsController::get_teacher_average_rating(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/classera-core-code/app/Controller/RatingSchoolsController.php on line 35 and exactly 1 expected

```
public function get_teacher_average_rating($result)
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->loadModel('Rating');
        if($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            $author_id = $this->request->query('author_id');//
            $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id), 'fields'=> array('AVG(Rating.value) as averageRating'), 'recursive' =>-1));

            $average = $rate[0][0]['averageRating'];
            $result = array('success'=>'1' , 'average' => $average );
        }
        else{
            $result = array('success'=>'0','message'=>'request type is not GET');
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }





public function set_teacher_average_rating()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
              $this->loadModel('Rating');

                $average = $this->get_teacher_average_rating();
                $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id) , 'recursive' =>-1));
                                echo json_encode($average );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks very clear: 'Too few arguments to function RatingSchoolsController::get_teacher_average_rating(), 0 passed'. You are not passing a parameter to `get_teacher_average_rating` and so it is failing.

Your method doesn't appear to actually need the value of `$result` passed in so you should be able to get rid of it from the method:-

```
public function get_teacher_average_rating() {
    ...
}
```